# How can I check the output of the program started by the "start" command in Windows in Python?

Tags: java, python, mysql, windows, command-prompt

I am writing an installation procedure in Python 3.4.3 that will install Java and MySQL if the required versions from the program it is installing are not installed (with user permission of course). Currently I'm doing this only for Windows. Other operating systems will come later. I'm using the commands: java -version and mysql --version to check if they have been installed properly (i.e. they are on the PATH environment). I had the problem that the current command prompt wouldn't know about the updated PATH environment after installing Java and MySQL. Because of this I implemented this code:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen("start cmd.exe /C \"java -version\ ",
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This solved that problem. However, I want to check the output of these commands so I can check to make sure Java and MySQL were installed correctly and that the correct versions are being used. When I try to check stdout or stderr, they are empty. I believe this is because those outputs are of "start" and not of java -version. Is there a way to redirect the output of java -version to the original command prompt? OR is there a way to access the output of the command prompt opened up by "start"? I have tried redirecting stderr to stdout (i.e. 2>&1) but I didn't really think that would help.

Comment: Do you have to use `start`? It's very easy to use `subprocess` to call `java -version` directly.

Comment: @drglove see my response to the answer by Pruthvi Raj

Comment: I can't reproduce using `start` to get a new `PATH`, presumably from the registry. The child just inherits the current environment. Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces this? Even so, it seems you could just use `start java -version`, without requiring another instance of cmd.exe.

Comment: `start` defaults to creating a new console. This is incompatible with inheriting the current standard handle values, unless they're passed in the process `STARTUPINFO`. cmd doesn't do this, since it would only work with `CreateProcess` (and not `ShellExecuteEx`, which it uses for everything that's not an EXE). But if you use `start /b` to stay attached to the current console (i.e. the current conhost.exe instance), then you will be able to inherit standard handles that have been redirected to pipes or files.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["java","-version"])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The issue is that when I try to check the output in the command prompt that was used to install Java, it doesn't recognize it because the Path for that current command prompt has not been updated. That's why I'm using start, to check in a new fresh command prompt